# Swift socket.io .emit() doesn't fire

Tags: ios, swift, sockets

I'm new to sockets and i'm stuck with the following problem, i use [this](https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-client-swift) library to connect my app to my nodejs server.
I'd like to know why if i call socket.emit() in the following way doesn't work:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    var socket: SocketIOClient = SocketIOClient(socketURL: NSURL(string: "myhosturl")!)

    socket.emit("ping","some data");
    socket.connect();
}
```

It doesn't work neither swiping socket.emit and socket.connect functions but if I trigger the socket.emit function by clicking a button it works:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
   var socket: SocketIOClient = SocketIOClient(socketURL: NSURL(string: "myhosturl")!)
   socket.connect();
}

@IBAction func sendMessage(sender: AnyObject) {
   socket.emit("ping","some data");
}
```

I think i'm missing something here, it would be great is someone could explain this to me

Comment: Don't know much about this library or your implementation, but it seems like asking the socket to emit before its connected wouldn't work, which is why it works fine in your second example but not in your first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sockets require a connection before emit is called. You should probably wait until there is a connection before u emit. Try this:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    let socket = SocketIOClient(socketURL: NSURL(string: "myhosturl")!)
    socket.on("connect") { _, _ in
        print("socket connected")
        socket.emit("ping", "data")
    }
    socket.on("ping") { _, _ in
        print("ping received")
    }
    socket.connect()
}
```